# I need to make schedule automatic delete from database stored on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have data in Mysql databse that has col: date (stored as TIMESTAMP) and i want to delete all items that stored for more that 3 months in the DB.
I store the database on Amazon and i'm not sure how to make this schedule delete works.

any ideas? is there any easy way to do it from one of AWS options?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS only provides the database infra, but they don't care about the data you put in it. 
To do what you want, you need a cron-like tool. Can't you run the mysql event scheduler, or a cron job to delete your old records?

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no such tool on AWS yet (maybe see the SWF service for a workaround, but it is not that easy to use...)

edit: if you use RDS, then I think you cannot use the event scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Amazon doesn't provide cron/scheduled job for RDS/Database as fas as I know. You must have to create cron job on EC2 or create event on mysql/RDS.